in R, package: berryfuntions, function: climategraph, How do I Scale my Ylab correctly
I want to create a Walter Lieth Diagram in R with the package berryfunctions in the function climateGraph. None of my Rainvalues exceed 600mm but I want my ylim to show 600. How do I do that and also how do I get my temperature to stop at 50C°? Because everything above is useless information. Thanks in advance!
MY script looks like this:
climateGraph(tempC, rainC, main = titleC,
    units = c("\U{00B0}C", "mm"),
    labs = c("J", "F", "M", "A", "M", "J", "J", "A", "S", "O", "N", "N"),
    textprop = 0.25,
    ylim = range(temp, rain/0.8),
    compress = TRUE,
    ticklab = -8:30 * 10,
    ticklin = -15:60 * 5,
    box =TRUE,
    mar = c(1.5, 6, 4.5, 0.2),
    keeppar = TRUE,
    colrain = "blue",
    coltemp = "red",
    lwd = 2,
    arghumi = NULL,
    argarid = NULL,
    argcomp = NULL,
    arggrid = NULL,
    argtext = NULL)
mtext("Temperatur in C°",side=2,line=3,outer=FALSE) mtext("Niederschlag in mm", side=2,line=-57,outer=FALSE)

I tried to change the ylim variable with temp>50 for example but it didn't work.
